# Declaring Constants outside of a subroutine

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, declaration

This is more of varification, but i want to be sure before i start altering some old code to clean it up.

If you have private varibales declared inside a module but outside a subroutine, when are these actually created. For example, this is how a module is set up:

```
'Local objects.....
'Function Main.....
'Subroutines.......
Private Constants..
Private variables..
More Subroutines...
```

If those variables are only used in one subroutine, should they be declared inside that subroutine or in the local objects or right outside the subroutine as they are now?

Thanks!

Comment: Without knowing how these variables are used, it's impossible to say. Are the values of the variables reset/cleared every time the methods are called? Or is the value left behind by a previous call consumed by the next call to the method?

Answer (score 3):

The CLR has no support for modules or module variables so modules become static classes and module variables become static fields.

As a rule, variables should be declared as close to the point they are used as possible. Their scope should also be as constrained as possible.

Turning a variable into a field is a pretty bad coding practice for several reasons:

- It is extremely easy to make a mistake and reuse the same field in another part of your module, creating unexpected conditions.
- You increase the lifetime of the objects in the variable significantly. Typically, once you exit the method, the variable is available for garbage collection. By turning it into a static field, the object will stay alive until it's replaced or the application terminates
- Multiple threads will be able to see and access the same static field, potentially creating race conditions. Given how many things work asynchrously nowadays, this can be a significant problem

Comment: While your points are all valid, you seem to make the assumption that the value of the field shouldn't be persisted between calls, which the OP doesn't make clear. For example, if I have an integer `numberOfTimesCalled` that is incremented for each call, that should absolutely be a field and not a local. Following this advice blindly could cause a break in application logic!

Comment: You assume only a single caller will touch this *static* field and there is no chance that some other call will find this value accidentally. Persisting state in static fields is error-prone and much more likely to cause unexpected behaviors. It's easier to pass state as a state object. This also makes it easier to extend the code eg by using a database or cache in the future to keep multiple values, or test it without worrying about leaking data from one session to the next

Comment: From @PanagiotisKanavos: `As a rule, variables should be declared as close to the point they are used as possible. Their scope should also be as constrained as possible.` is the answer.

Comment: This *static* field isn't necessarily *public*, and so it is perfectly feasible practise to store that state in a field *depending on the implementation*. There are plenty of cases where you wouldn't necessarily *want* to expose "state values" to the caller to be passed back in later: if a static class is managing a queue of work that the user can add to (regardless of the merit of that design in itself), it is absolutely correct to create a private static field to store the queue of work, and NOT to require that to be passed in to each method call.

Comment: The part of your answer that @DanVerdolino quoted is absolutely correct, but I find the rest of your answer seems to advocate never using fields. In fact we don't know whether the fields in the OP's code are bad practise, or necessary requirement.

Comment: We are talking about *static* fields here. Using *static* fields is rarely a good idea